# Selenium Java class annotations for Page Object

Tags: java, selenium, annotations

Can you help me with class(page) annotations in Page Object pattern?
For example: I have "Contacts" WebElement in upper menu and footer. With the same locator.
I know, that I can annotate Footer.class with some annotation and UpperMenu.class too, where I can also put selector for whole page. And tests will check page selector at first and then element selector. It will be like: "footer_page_selector"+"contacts" = "footer_page_contacts"

May be I can use @FindBy annotations for classes too?

```
@Annotation(css= .footer)
class Footer {
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(@title, contact)]") private WebElement contact;
}


@Annotation(css= .upper_menu)
class UpperMenu{
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(@title, contact)]") private WebElement contact;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some pseudo code of what you would like to have?

Comment: Sure. Added to my post

Answer (score 1):

Selenium does not provide such feature by default. You can use two options here:

1. Use some Selenium wrapper like  [yandex-qatools/htmlelements](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements) (see the sxample on their GH page)
2. Have a page object that would store header and footer as its fields (say it would have the name `CommonParts`). Then you can initiate page object targeting "contacts" in footer or in header using the same page class. When you create an instance you use corresponding field of `CommonParts` as a *search context*. In this case you will need your "contacts" locator to be relative (i.e. in xPath case it could start from `./`). See more detailed explanation [here](https://www.webelement.click/en/pagefactory_relative_lookup_java).